# I actually feel absolutely nothing ? or felt absolutely?

Tags: tense

> 12: Depression is so much misunderstood and still so powerful. If you asked me what I was feeling, I would tell you **I actually feel absolutely nothing**, I try so hard to feel something but nothing works.

I actually feel absolutely nothing ? or felt absolutely ?

via: [Depression Sayings](https://therightmessages.com/depression-quotes-sayings/)

Answer (score 1):

Both are acceptable there:

**If you asked me...**

> ... I would tell you that I feel nothing
>
> ... I would tell you that I felt nothing

The past tense **felt** is detached from "the Now", whereas the speaker is psychologically present in **feels**.